Is there a method for getting a keyboard input thru ASM with protected mode in C++, from the x86 PC keyboard controller?
I've been working on a kernel that my system needs. I've implement some functions that acts as a wrapper for I/O.
But somehow, the get_char() only returns 0.
Code:
uint8_t inb(uint16_t port) {
    uint8_t result;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("inb %1, %0" : "=a"(result) : "Nd"(port));
    return result;
}

void timeout() {

}
// Simple scancode to ASCII conversion (only handling basic characters for example purposes)

char scancode_to_ascii(uint8_t scancode) {
    char scancodeToAscii[128] = {
        0,   27, '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', /* 9 */
        '9', '0', '-', '=', '\b', /* Backspace */
        '\t', /* Tab */
        'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', /* 19 */
        't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '[', ']', '\n', /* Enter key */
        0, /* 29   - Control */
        'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', /* 39 */
        '\'', '`', 0, /* Left shift */
        '\\', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', /* 49 */
        'm', ',', '.', '/', 0, /* Right shift */
        '*',
        0, /* All other keys are undefined */
    };
    return scancodeToAscii[scancode];
}
char get_char() {
    // Wait for a key press by polling the keyboard status port
    while (!(inb(0x60) & 0x01)) {
        // Busy-wait until data is available in the output buffer
    }
    // Now read the scancode from the keyboard data port (0x60)
    uint8_t scancode = inb(0x60);
    if (scancode > 0) {
        // Convert the scancode to ASCII, ignoring key releases
        return scancode_to_ascii(scancode);
    } 
    return 0;
}
void cin(const char* prompt, int length, char* buffer) {
    int pos = 0;

    // Display the prompt
    cout_string(prompt, pos);
    pos += strlen(prompt);

    // Read input from keyboard
    int index = 0;
    char c;
    int write = 1;
    while (index < length - 1) { // Leave space for null terminator
        char temp = c;
        c = get_char();

        // Check for Enter key (ASCII 13)
        if (c == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        // Check for Backspace (ASCII 8)
        else if (c == '\b') {
            if (index > 0) {
                pos--;
                // Clear the character on screen
                cout(' ', pos);
                index--;
                continue;
            }
        }
        // Prints the char to the screen
        else if ((temp != c) && (c > 0)) {
            if (1) {
                cout(c, pos);
                pos++;
                buffer[index++] = c;
                write = 0;
            }
            else {
                write = 1;
            }
        }
        timeout();
    }
    buffer[index] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the string
    cout('s', 0);
}

I tried renaming 0 on the scancode map to something readable, but it didn't show up. I've also tried to detect whether the output is 0 and it is.
EDIT: I made it worked, but somehow some keys like "g" doesnt type in.

Your wait_for_keypress is also reading the keyboard data port (0x60 instead of 0x64), so might be discarding your actual input (unless this is a typo in the question).

Ty, but I changed the port to 0x64 and now everytime i press the key it shows "You entered" instead of waiting for another keyboard press

I just want to clear up a possible confusion. In order to wait for a key, you should read the status register 0x64 (and test bit 0) , to get the actual scancode after that you want to read 0x60. You should probably also make sure the keyboard's using the scancode set you expect, see https://wiki.osdev.org/PS/2_Keyboard and https://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller for some relevant information.
